# Nexus 7 Responsive CSS - strange y-axis movement for no obvious reason

Tags: google-chrome, width, viewport

I'm wondering if anyone else has experience in this issue. I'm working on a responsive build, which works fine on everything but my Nexus 4 and Nexus 7. Both browsers render the page with a tiny amount of horizontal scrolling. I know nothing is "overlapping" body, or any parent containers, as I've stripped the code back to just two divs and it still renders it wrong. It's driving me insane!

Here's the simple code, but you'll need to view to view this code on a real page to see the effect I'm talking about.

Meta viewport tag;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

CSS;

```
body, html, div { margin:0; padding:0; }
.outer { background:grey; width:100%; }
.inner { background:silver; height:10em; max-width:10em; margin:0 auto; }
```

and the HTML;

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
    <p>Test Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

It's so simple, so I have no idea what's up! Help!

Comment: Apparently you can't do anything about it. Chrome on Nexus7 always display a horizontal scrollbar unfortunatly.

Comment: This seems to come and go for me now. I've got a Nexus 4 and 7, and this comes and goes with little reason...